# Proving $\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^3} < \frac1n-\frac1{n^3}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that the sequence of closed intervals

$\left[ \dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n^3}~~,~~ \dfrac1n+\dfrac1{n^3}\right]$ for $n>2$ are disjoint.

For this to be true I guess we could show that the minimum of the interval is larger than the maxixmum of the subsequent interval :

$\dfrac1{n+1}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^3} < \dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n^3}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, 
$n>2$.

How could we prove this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the fractions under common denominator and after some calculation you will get:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac1{(n+1)^3} \le \frac 1n - \frac 1{n^3} \iff 1 + 3n + 2n^2 <n^4$$

Now use induction to prove that this is true for $n\ge 2$

Obviously it's true for $n=2$, as $16>15$. Now assume it holds for $k$ and we have:

$$1 + 3(k+1) + 2(k+1)^2 = (1+3k + 2k^2) + 5 + 4k < k^4 + 4k + 5 < (k+1)^4$$

where we used the hypothesis and the fact that $k\ge2$